# How can I create a C LinkedList that holds dynamically set data types

Tags: c, linked-list, custom-data-type

In **`C`** :

```
struct node {
   int data;
   int key;
   struct node *next;
};
```

The above **`C`** data structure can only hold the set data types, that is, `int data` and `int key`.

In **`Java`** :

```
List<?> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can I create a **`C`** `LinkedList` that holds dynamically set data types?

The idea is :

```
struct node {
   <?> data;
   <?> key;
   struct node *next;
};
```

So that I can do :

```
List<String> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**OR**

```
List<MyCustomObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

in **C**

```
struct node {
   <String> data;
   <String> key;
   struct node *next;
};
```

**OR**

```
struct node {
   <MyCustomObject> data;
   <MyCustomObject> key;
   struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: There are no dynamic types in C. The only possible method would be void* pointers. But you'd still need specific add, get and remove for each implementation

Comment: `new` is not C, it's C++

Comment: But it is in Java

Comment: They are many possibility, but you all need to code it yourself. Note that Arraylist in java is not a the same thing that a linkedlist in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because **dynamic [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) do not exist** in general **in C**. Check by reading the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

What you might do is implementing some kind of [tagged union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), and make a list containing these (or perhaps a list containing some *pointers* to them, but you need to decide on some [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) strategy and related coding conventions).

How to implement such tagged union types is different question. For inspiration, look into Glib [GVariant](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html) type (but there are other ways to do that; one example is Python value type, read more about it in [extending Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) chapter; or some `struct` containing some `union`, or some `union` of `struct` all starting with a common discriminating field, or some `union` of pointers to such `struct`, etc.), and study the [source code](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.54/) of that implementation in Glib, which is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

You could also consider some [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approach, e.g. generating some C code from some description of your data types. Look into [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) or [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN) for inspiration.

BTW, the [SGLIB](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) header-mostly library uses a lot of [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) techniques (with huge C macros) to provide "generic" containers.

Be also aware of the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of your C implementation. In some cases, it might help understanding it (e.g. if you decide to use [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer)). Notice that many basic C types (`int`, `long`, `char`, data [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)), [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)) have essentially different representations (different sizes, different [alignments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), different ways of being passed as arguments and returned as results - e.g. in various [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) or on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) and perhaps even different [address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (think of [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) where function pointers are in a different space than data and could even have different sizes than data pointers).

Comment: This answer prove that the question is too broad XD

Comment: @Stargateur: I don't pretend to have *proved* that the question is too broad, even if of course we know it is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Data should be a `void *`. You will then need to implicitly cast it to whatever pointer type it needs to be.

Comment: And probably add another attribute that tells you what the type is.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case. Think of dealing only with `float` and `short` (not pointers to them) directly